# AppCompat ActionBar restoring original layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

In my app, I use a MainActivity for storing the main layout (DrawerLayout, with a CoordinatorLayout as content root, with the toolbar and fragment holder in it), and various fragments as screens.

On one particular screen I'd like to expand the ActionBar to a certain size, and give it specific content (remove the toggle button, menu bar, etc., and specify my own layout). It is done by `MainActivity.toolbar.setCustomView();`. It works pretty well, however when I navigate to a different fragment, I'd like to restore the original layout. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Try it with: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in order to remove your custom view and restore the AppCompat ActionBar you can call setDisplayOptions.

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```